# testlink integration with robotframework

Tags: integration, robotframework, testlink

I am looking for testlink integration with robotframework but no success so far.
Problem I have is how to write tests in robotframework and how to link with testlink. I mean what is the format of writing tests in testlink so that robotframework will understand and execute it and how it will be achived.

I have looked at https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-tmlibrary/ but no luck in how to use this properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

https://github.com/dmizverev/robot-framework-library/blob/master/listener/TestLinkListener.py

or

https://github.com/hayzer/robotframework2testlink

These two implementation are using the Robot Listener and using Testlink APIs. The method end_test() does the job to update the result.

If you don't have test suite, testcase, or test plan created before running the robot test execution. It can be automated. Implement start_suite() method and use test link API to create the suite and use start_test() method to create testcase and associate to test plan.

While running robot from cli append with **--listener classname**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to this. 
If you have tons of manual tests in Testlink and automate them independently with robotframework. Or you have two legacy sets of tests(manual and automated) that you are trying to bring together.

You can use jenkins to integrate robot and testlink. You'll have to have same testcase names in testlink and robot suites. Also you'll have to define additional custom keyword in testlink for automated tests that duplicates testcase name. There are both [Testlink jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/TestLink+Plugin) and [Robotframework jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin) available for this. Also there are some useful forks that support test platforms from testlink or custom testplan fields. 
Basically, you'll have to obtain TC names from a testplan in jenkins job and feed robot with those in any way (e.g. -t "$TCNAME") After that, execution results can be passed back to TL.

This approach lets you have independent test structure in robot and testlink and better integrate with other processes during development (pipelines in CI/CD, test planning for huge test suites), but you'll have to do some additional job of tracking two sets of tests.